# Ethernet interface hang

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, network-adapter

I have a custom board running a Marvell 3700 with SMP enabled. Due to driver customizations, I had to implement a spinlock in the ndo_start_xmit function (TX function) of the driver to avoid the 2 cores from competing. (My driver customization uses some shared variables which cannot be avoided).

When testing with iperf3 and TCP, I often see that an interface hangs and it doesn't xmit anymore. This doesn't happen alway, but only after sustained iperfs. The interface's ifconfig TX statstics doesn't increase when I try to ping a host on that interface. I think what's happening is that the skbs are not being released in a race condition between 2 cores which is causing the skbs to get exhausted eventually.

I tried doing XPS by setting echo 1 > /sys/class/net/ethX/queues/txN/xps_cpus for all interfaces and TX-Qs. My understanding was that each of these TX-Qs would be serviced by CPU #1 which should prevent the race condition. Is that correct? Any other suggestions/pointers would be helpful.

Thank you.